# Sorting on groups, then on two fields depending on group

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I want to sort a list of objects depending on three fields. First which group it belongs to and then, depending on which group it belongs to, sort on two different date fields.

Say we have an object `Case` with three fields, `String status`, `LocalDate startedDate`, and 
`LocalDate deletedDate`. Status can be either `"Active"` or `"Deleted"` while `startedDate` and `deletedDate` are dates. A `Case` has a `deletedDate` iff its `Status == "Deleted"`.

Anyone got ideas on a good solution for sorting a list of objects using the following rules:

- First sort on status
- If status is "Active" sort on startedDate, descending.
- If status is "Deleted" sort on deletedDate, descending.

Say this is the data we start with:

```
Name, Created date, Status,  Deleted date
xxx,  2019-01-01,   Deleted, 2018-02-01
xxx,  2019-01-01,   Active,  NULL
xxx,  2018-01-01,   Deleted, 2019-02-01
xxx,  2018-01-01,   Active,  NULL
```

I tried doing this, but this doesn't take the actual status set into consideration:

```
cases.sort(Comparator.comparing(Case::getStatus).thenComparing(Case::getCreatedDate).reversed().thenComparing(Case::getDeletedDate).reversed();
```

..which will produce this result:

```
Name, Created date, Status,  Deleted date
xxx,  2019-01-01,   Active,  NULL
xxx,  2018-01-01,   Active,  NULL
xxx,  2019-01-01,   Deleted, 2019-02-01
xxx,  2018-01-01,   Deleted, 2018-02-01
```

This is the result I want when sorting four cases:

```
Name, Created date, Status,  Deleted date
xxx,  2019-01-01,   Active,  NULL
xxx,  2018-01-01,   Active,  NULL
xxx,  2018-01-01,   Deleted, 2019-02-01
xxx,  2019-01-01,   Deleted, 2018-02-01
```

Comment: Build a comparator that first checks the status and if both have the same status you compare the relevant dates. It's not that hard - just try something and show us what you've got.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I have a line in my question describing what I tried. I'm quite new to Java so I don't know where to go from here. I'm also interested in learning best practices and I 'd like to avoid hard coding the status strings if possible.

Comment: What's the return type of `Case.getStatus()`?

Comment: @dpr Its a string. Sorry for not pointing that out earlier.

Comment: And what's the result you get when sorting a list with the Comparator mentioned in your question? It's probably best to add a complete example, to see how you use the comparator, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that with your approach you'd first sort by status, then by created date and finally by deleted date. Taking into account that you'd need to only reserve the date comparators that approach should work unless elements are deleted out of order, i.e. if e1 had been created before e2 but e2 has been deleted after e1 you'd get the wrong order.

To compare elements based on their status you could provide a secondary comparator that uses the status to decide which property to compare:

```
Comparator.comparing( Case::getStatus )
          .thenComparing( c -> "Active".equals( c.getStatus() ) ? c.getCreatedDate() : c.getDeletedDate(), 
                          Comparator.reverseOrder() );
```

Edit: If the deleted date is null for all active elements you could also use 2 different date comparators like you did, just in a reversed order:

```
Comparator.comparing( Case::getStatus )
          .thenComparing( Case::getDeletedDate, Comparator.nullsFirst( Comparator.reverseOrder() ) )
          .thenComparing( Case::getCreatedDate, Comparator.nullsFirst( Comparator.reverseOrder() ) );
```

Here we'd use the fact that active elements have a null deletedDate and thus the result of that comparison would be 0. Deleted elements would first be sorted by their deletedDate and, if those are still the same, by their createdDate - if that's ok for you.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

reversed() has to be a parameter of thenComparing (using  Comparator.reverseOrder()), else you reverse the complete comparator.

E.g. something like:

```
cases.sort(Comparator
.comparing(Case::getStatus)
.thenComparing(Case::getRelevantDate, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

where getRelevantDate gets the relevant date: getCreatedDate for status == active, getDeletedDate for status == Deleted

Of course, if the method would be too use case specific, you could also implement `getRelevantDate` as a private helper method where you define the comparator, and then use `this::getRelevantDate`.

Comment: yup, thus deleted my comment; the other answer does the same thing.